# why Youtube Video is Not Playing in webview android

Tags: android, webview, youtube, sdk, html5-video

i have simple webView in android and i want to play video in that through URL.
but it showing error video is not able to play in webview.
[this error is coming while playing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpwD2.png)

here is my source code:-

```
WebView webView;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.livepage);
    //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_bottom7);
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLmI8_hVUqA251PzK7OSvQw");
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new loadWebView());
}

private class loadWebView extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
}
```

here is menifest:-

```
<application
   ...
   android:supportsRtl="true"
   android:largeHeap="true"
   android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
```

thanks in advance

Comment: https://inducesmile.com/android/how-to-play-youtube-video-inside-android-webview-using-video-url/

Answer (score 3):

yes i found my solution of this question,
here solution,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_bottom7);
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLmI8_hVUqA251PzK7OSvQw");

    webView.setWebViewClient(new loadWebView());
}
private class loadWebView extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

need to add

```
webSetting.setDomStorageEnable(true);
```

working fine for me !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

First enable

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

And then

If you click on any link inside the webpage of the WebView, that page will not be loaded inside your WebView. In order to do that you need to extend your class from WebViewClient and override its method. Its syntax is:

```
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 String frameVideo = "<html><body>Video From YouTube<br><iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/47yJ2XCRLZs\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

    WebView displayYoutubeVideo = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mWebView);
    displayYoutubeVideo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    WebSettings webSettings = displayYoutubeVideo.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    displayYoutubeVideo.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

**or you can try this integrate youtube api
Yes! Check out the Android Youtube Player API and the YouTube API.**

[Android Player:](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)

[YouTube API:](https://developers.google.com/youtube/)

[YouTube Player API Sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/)

[and follow this link to get video from channel](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/ytdl/MainActivity.java#L391)

Comment: @Abhay did you get any error because it working on my real device just check in to real device

Comment: can u check with my url..i want to open channel first and onclick video it should play..

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you haven't added a youtube video link. You are using a youtube channel url. Anyway try this. It works well.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String frameVideo = "<html><body><iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/PMBcMBhsm80\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

    WebView displayYoutubeVideo = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mWebView);
    displayYoutubeVideo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    WebSettings webSettings = displayYoutubeVideo.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    displayYoutubeVideo.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
}
```

Comment: first i want to open my channel and than i want to play video.

Comment: Did you add Internet permission and relevant permissions in manifest?

Comment: yes.. i have added permission..my channel page is opening but while playing video its showinh..an error occured

Comment: @Abhay - I have tested your code with a real device. First it shows a youtube channel and when I clicked on it , the videos is working properly. Please test this with another device

Comment: i m going to chek